# What are the fractal parameters?

Tags: fractals

There are so many fractal which are not uniquely characterize by some fractal parameters like Fractal dimension, Succolarity, Lacunarity, Morphological entropy. Can you suggest some fractal parameters which would be able to characterize distinctly from other fractals?

Comment: Is there even a well-defined definition of fractal to use to universally categorize them in this manner?

Comment: Yes there is a organized well defined definition of fractals. See any book on fractal geometry, like Fractals everywhere, Fractal geometry of nature, fractals geometry by Falconer, G edgar etc. 

If you do not get the question properly that is fine to make you understand again. But do not ask such bogus question.

Comment: @Sk:  I strongly disagree with your comment.  Jeremy's question is perfectly legitimate and very to-the-point.  I have seen several non-equivalent potential definitions of the word "fractal", and I do not believe any of them would find universal acceptance as "the" definition.

Your attack on Jeremy's comment strikes me as particularly inappropriate.  Even if it had been a naive and unhelpful question (which it most emphatically is not), there is no call for an uncivil response.

Comment: I'm also not quite sure what to make of the parameters you've listed.  I've never heard of succolarity or lacunarity (at least not in this precise context), so a brief explanation in the question would help clarify things.  By "morphological entropy" I guess you may mean what I would call "topological entropy", but that assumes the presence of an underlying dynamical system, which you didn't mention.  Finally, "fractal dimension" is not a precisely defined concept, but rather a general one that subsumes Hausdorff dimension, box dimension, packing dimension, etc.

Comment: I am not going to make you argue in this way. wHAT i WANT TO SAY IS THE FUNDA OF FRACTAL IS QUITE CLEAR. AND YOU KNOW THIS SUBJECT IS POPULAR SINCE LAST 30 YRS OR SO. 

I ASKED A PRECISE QUESTION...IF YOU HAVE ANSWER LET ME,ONE SHOULD NOT DEVIATE ME FROM THE QUESTION.

MORPHOLOGICAL ENTROPY IS NOT TOPOLOGICAL ENTROPY, THIS IS A PARAMETER SIGNIFIES THE SHAPE OF THE FRACTAL, THIS BASICALLY PERT OF MATHEMATICAL MORPHOLOGY.

Comment: Abuse of commenters (c.f. "But do not ask such bogus question") is inappropriate. Typing in allcaps is also a sure way to discredit yourself.

Comment: Scott: it looks like the poster hit Caps Lock not Shift at "What I want...". Not that I am sympathetic to his arcument or the question!

Comment: "Succolarity" in particular only has 431 Google results, which makes me suspicious of it as a mathematical term; although they do seem to relate to fractals. At least with "Lacunarity" one can guess at a meaning (and it has a reasonable number of Google hits). 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fractal curvature might be the answer. In differential or convex geometry, you need curvature to classify sets up to isometry. So it seems natural to introduce curvature for "fractals" in an attempt to get a finer geometric description. This has been done for mostly self-similar fractals by Winter, Zähle, Rataj, Kombrink, and me (Bohl, formerly Rothe). The full generalization to self-conformal sets is my upcoming PhD thesis.

Philosophically, and literally in differential geometry, curvature takes the second derivative of "coordinates" into account. In contrast, the Hausdorff and packing measures, most other dimensions, Minkowski content (=lacunarity), and surface content are only sensitive to the first derivative. Topological entropy is related to Gibbs / equilibrum measures if you have some kind of iterated function system, and these measures also belong to first order geometry.

Answer (score 3):

It does matter how you are thinking of fractals. If you are thinking of all sets of Hausdorff dimension that is not integral, then there is essentially no chance of having a number of real-valued invariants that distinguish them. There are always going to be too many sets, I believe. If you use self-similarity (of some kind), or particular ways of generating sets, there is possibly a more reasonable question, of how to find quantitative measures to distinguish them.